# Is there a good way to use mocks as inputs to Dataflow tests?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to test a `DoFn<KV<String, twitter4j.Status>, String>` implementation, and provide test data as input.  One avenue I was exploring was to use a `Mockito.mock` object as input, since there are a large number of abstract methods to implement otherwise.  However, calling the mocked methods in my `DoFn` alters the object, such that the test framework complains that "*Values must not be mutated in any way after being output*".

Is there an alternative way to accomplish what I'm trying here?  The test code is roughly:

```
 Status status = mock(Status.class, withSettings().serializable());
 when(status.getText()).thenReturn("bar");

 Pipeline p = TestPipeline.create();
 PCollection<String> strings = p
     .apply(Create.of(KV.of("foo", status)))
     .apply(MapElements.via(new TwitterUtils.StatusToJsonFn()));

 DataflowAssert.thatSingleton(strings).isEqualTo(...);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out DoFnTester, which allows you to test a DoFn by providing input data and asserting on the results: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/testing-your-pipeline

Comment: Very nice.  Thank you!

Comment: Updated link: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/pipelines/test-your-pipeline/

Comment: Additionally, with the latest version of Beam, the DoFnTester is deprecated in favour of using TestPipeline with the DirectRunner.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to create an immutable wrapper class:

```
class StatusWrapper implements Serializable {
    private Status status;
    private String mockText;

    // Constructor for real usage
    StatusWrapper(Status status) { this.status = status; }

    // Constructor for mocks
    StatusWrapper() {}

    StatusWrapper withMockText(String text) {
        this.mockText = text; return this;
    }

    Status toStatus() {
        if (status != null) {
            return status;
        }
        Status status = mock(Status.class);
        when(status.getText()).thenReturn(mockText);
        return status;
    }
}

Pipeline p = TestPipeline.create();
PCollection<String> strings = p
    .apply(Create.of(new StatusWrapper().withMockText("bar")))
    .apply(MapElements.via(new TwitterUtils.StatusToJsonFn()));
DataflowAssert.thatSingleton(strings).isEqualTo(...);
```

`StatusToJsonFn` will need to take `StatusWrapper` as an argument instead of `Status`, and call `toStatus()` on it - because if it takes `Status`, it will suffer from the same problem.

In a real pipeline this can be used like this:

```
PCollection<Status> realStatuses = ...;
PCollection<String> strings = realStatuses
    .apply(MapElements.via(StatusWrapper::new))
    .apply(MapElements.via(new TwitterUtils.StatusToJsonFn()));
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm wondering if MockSettings.stubOnly() would accomplish this as well, but I haven't had a chance to try it out.